# How to deploy multimodule project

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, jboss7.x

I have such a project scheme:

MainModule:

- Module1.jar + Module1.pom
- Module2.jar + Module2.pom
- MainModule.pom

Tell me please, what should I put into "%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\deployments\" to get successful deployment?

I have references in Module2.jar to Module1.

F.e.: Class1 is located in Module1.jar, Class2 is located in Module2.jar. I have:

```
public static void foo(Class1 obj){}
```

in Class2.java. All pom-files are supposedly correct. I have a dependency of Class1.java in Module2.pom.

If it is necessary, I can attach all pom-files and project structure.

Tell me, location scheme, please...!